# Java - How to split a string into arguments for a command

Tags: java

In a client server programm i have this line

```
    String line = inputStream.readLine();
    if (line.startsWith("/adduser")) {
      //do code
    }
```

example command " **/adduser -id 1022 -p SomePass** "
I know how to begin the process by the line.startswith , but how can i make the program to read what is after -id and put it in a value and same with -p.

Comment: try split() method:  String[] cmd = line.split()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could split the string and use a for loop to parse the resulting array for flags.

```
String line = inputStream.readLine();
   if (line.startsWith("/adduser")) {
      String[] arguments = line.split(" ");
      int id = 0;
      String password = "";

      for (int i = 0; i < arguments.length - 1; i++)
         if (arguments[i].equals("-id"))
            id = Integer.parseInt(arguments[i+1]);    // Assuming that your id values are integers.
         else if (arguments[i].equals("-p"))
            password = arguments[i+1];

      // Handle values
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work. I would suggest using some tests on those **id** and **pass** values before doing anything fancy with them.

```
    String[] line = "/adduser -id 1022 -p SomePass".split(" ");
    String id = line[2];
    String somePass = line[4];
```